# Removing ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: update-manager

The package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is showing up in Update Manager as having been downloaded but not installed. When I run `sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer` I get the message

```
 dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching ttf-mscorefonts-installer:amd64
```

I can't uncheck the box next to ttf-mscorefonts-installer in the Update Manager interface, and I can't install any other updates because I get the error message

> Requires installation of untrusted packages
>
> The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

How do I get rid of `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` so that it stops causing problems?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First trying this ->

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If it doesn't fix the problem, try removing the package with

```
sudo dpkg -r ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

EDIT:  remove --purge is equivalent to the purge command which removes configuration files along with the package.

More info is available [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, could you please explain in a little more detail what this command does?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, ttf-mscorefonts-installer stuck in half-installed state.

I was able to remove it using `dpkg` with the option `--force-all`:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

And then `dpkg --purge`:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```